# Why specifying std::ios::in for ifstream?

Tags: c++, std, fstream, ifstream

I want to use `ifstream` to load a font file into the memory and give it to FreeType. I find the standard I/O facilities a little discouraging. For now my question is why I have to specify `std::ios::in` for `ifstream`? The name `ifstream` already implies input operations, so why do we need this needless confusing things? Can we specify `ifstream` with `out`? What will happens if I don't specify it? From an example on cppreference:

`std::ifstream f1("test.bin", std::ios::binary);`

Here the default argument `std::ios::in` is not used. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For now my question is why I have to specify `std::ios::in` for ifstream?

You don't. It will always append the corresponding flag by the bitwise OR operation. The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) explicitly states that:

> First, performs the same steps as the default constructor, then
> associates the stream with a file by calling `rdbuf()->open(filename, mode | std::ios_base::in)`

> Can we specify ifstream with out?

Yes. This would just request the file buffer to open the file in writing mode as well, possibly creating it in the process. Of course, the `istream` interface will not allow for any output operations, but you may re-use the `filebuf` for other operations/streams without closing/re-opening the file.

Comment: Interesting, then why to repeat `std::ios_base::in` in defaults, if in the implementation it will be used no matter what? It confuses me because I think when I provide an argument defaults will not be used. And now I must actually go and look at the implementation to see if I should provide it or what.

Comment: @olekstolar I cannot tell you *why* certain things are as they are in the standard library. The I/O-stream interface of C++ is known to be somewhat obscure. Anyways, you do not have to look at any implementation, only at the documentation of the interface as it clearly tells you what you have to provide.